# How to invoke a function in another function

Tags: javascript

I am working on a sketch and having issues. I have a variable called "gridSize" that determines the gridSize, and a function  "fillScreen()" that populate the screen. If i set the gridSize by inputting the  desired grid size and invoking the function, the required grid appears. My issue is that the buttons I create to adjust the grid size doesn't seem to work. I have four buttons to adjust grid size - two course and two fine.

Also, when the game has just started, and the start button is  clicked, it should default to a 16 * 16 grid. That also does not work. The event listeners on my buttons are ok, so I have hit a  wall .

Here is the codepen:https://codepen.io/codeninja119/pen/ZEqqpPy?editors=1010

I was expecting the grid size to vary according to the selection of the button clicks. I tested the event listeners on the buttons, and they function correctly.

```
     let start = 0; // number of first cell
let new2; // new cells variable
let gridSize; // default number of rows and columns
//let initial = 0;
const screen = document.querySelector(".screen");
let miniDisplay = document.querySelector(".miniDisplay");

const  courseDecrement = document.querySelector(".courseDown");// this and below 3 variable declarations selects the increment and decrement buttons
const  fineDecrement = document.querySelector(".fineDown");
const courseIncement = document.querySelector(".courseUp");
const fineIncrement = document.querySelector(".fineUp");

const clear = document.querySelector(".clear"); // selects the clear button

if(gridSize < 16 || gridSize > 64){
  clearColours();
  screen.style.backgroundColor = "#af3131";
  let message = screen.innerHTML = "PLEASE CHOOSE A GRID SIZE BETWEEN 16 - 64.";
  
}

let sizeOfGrid = gridSize; // number of rows and columns
let dimension = 370.0/gridSize // width & height of each grid
let number; // variable for random number;




function drawW(){ // function to create new grids
  
  for(let cell = start; cell < gridSize; cell++){
    new2 = document.createElement("div"); //new cell created
    new2.style.border = "1px solid #837777"; // border colour of new cell
    new2.style.width = `${dimension}` + "px";
    new2.style.height = `${dimension}` + "px";
   // new2.classList.add("blocks");
  // document.querySelector(".blocks").style.flexShrink = "1";
    new2.style.fontSize = "3.5px";
    new2.style.boxSizing =  "border-box"; 
    new2.innerHTML = cell; // cell number is displayed
    new2.onmouseover = e => { // targets the squares and generates a random number
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = createRgbColour();
     };
    
    document.querySelector(".screen").appendChild(new2); // display is selected and new cell appended
   
  }
   start++; // start incremented to allow number on grid increase as one descends down the grid
   gridSize++; //variable to allow user to change the grid size
  
}
//drawW();


function fillScreen(){ // function that draws the required number of rows
  for(let rows = 0; rows < sizeOfGrid; rows++){
    drawW();
  }
}
//fillScreen();



function randomNumberMake(){ //generates a whole number between 0 - 255
  number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return number;
}

function createRgbColour(){ //returns the RGB expression for the colours
   return `rgb( ${randomNumberMake()}, ${randomNumberMake()}, ${randomNumberMake()} )`;
}

function clearColours(){
 
  screen.innerHTML = "";
  //screen.style.backgroundColor = "#e1e4ea";
  gridSize = 0;
  miniDisplay.innerHTML = "000";
}

 function gameBegin(){ // game starts with 16 x 16 default grid size
  screen.innerHTML = ""; // clears the display
  miniDisplay.innerHTML = 16;
  gridSize = 16;
  fillScreen();
 }

function courseSubtract(){ // subtracts 10 from the grid size
    courseDecrement.onclick = () =>  {
      gridSize -= 10;
      miniDisplay.innerHTML = gridSize;
      console.log(miniDisplay.innerHTML);
      fillScreen();
   }
}
courseSubtract();

function fineSubtract(){ // subtracts 2 from the grid size
  fineDecrement.onclick = () => {
    gridSize -= 2;
    miniDisplay.innerHTML = "";
    miniDisplay.innerHTML = gridSize;
    console.log(miniDisplay.innerHTML);
    fillScreen();
  }
}
fineSubtract();

function courseAdd(){ // adds 10 to the grid size
  courseIncement.onclick = () => {
    gridSize += 10;
    miniDisplay.innerHTML = "";
    miniDisplay.innerHTML = gridSize;
    console.log(miniDisplay.innerHTML);
    fillScreen();
  }
}
courseAdd();

function fineAdd(){ // adds 2 to the grid size
  fineIncrement.onclick = () => {
    gridSize += 2;
    miniDisplay.innerHTML = "";
    miniDisplay.innerHTML = gridSize;
    console.log(miniDisplay.innerHTML);
    fillScreen();
  }
}
fineAdd();



const pageLoad = document.createElement("img"); // creates new element for page load image 
pageLoad.src = "https://github.com/brian-w119/my-images/blob/main/SKETCH.gif?raw=true";

function imageOnPageload(){ // attaches image to screen
  //clearColours();
  screen.appendChild(pageLoad);
}



window.onload = () => { //cleas the screen and plays intro animation
 // clearColours();
  imageOnPageload();
  setTimeout(displayRules, 3000);
}



const instruction = ["Select a grid size between 16 and 64, then press ENTER. Press START to begin."];
const speed = 60;
let textPosition = 0;

function displayRules(){ //function for typewriter effect
    miniDisplay.innerHTML = "000";
    screen.innerHTML = instruction[0].substring(0,textPosition);
    if(textPosition++ != instruction[0].length){
      setTimeout(displayRules, speed);
   }
} 





















type here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code of JS, replace with exisiting one , Is it same which you are looking for? let me know if anything else I can help you in this

```
<script>
  let start = 0; // number of first cell
  let new2; // new cells variable
  let gridSize; // default number of rows and columns
  //let initial = 0;
  const screen = document.querySelector(".screen");
  let miniDisplay = document.querySelector(".miniDisplay");

  const courseDecrement = document.querySelector(".courseDown"); // this and below 3 variable declarations selects the increment and decrement buttons
  const fineDecrement = document.querySelector(".fineDown");
  const courseIncement = document.querySelector(".courseUp");
  const fineIncrement = document.querySelector(".fineUp");

  const clear = document.querySelector(".clear"); // selects the clear button

  if (gridSize < 16 || gridSize > 64) {
    clearColours();
    screen.style.backgroundColor = "#af3131";
    let message = (screen.innerHTML =
      "PLEASE CHOOSE A GRID SIZE BETWEEN 16 - 64.");
  }

  let sizeOfGrid = gridSize; // number of rows and columns
  let dimension = 370.0 / gridSize; // width & height of each grid
  let number; // variable for random number;

  function drawW() {
    // function to create new grids
    console.log("dimension",dimension);
    for (let cell = 0; cell < gridSize; cell++) {
      new2 = document.createElement("div"); //new cell created
      new2.style.border = "1px solid #837777"; // border colour of new cell
      new2.style.width = `${dimension}` + "px";
      new2.style.height = `${dimension}` + "px";
      // new2.classList.add("blocks");
      // document.querySelector(".blocks").style.flexShrink = "1";
      new2.style.fontSize = "3.5px";
      new2.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
      new2.innerHTML = cell; // cell number is displayed
      new2.onmouseover = (e) => {
        // targets the squares and generates a random number
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = createRgbColour();
      };

      document.querySelector(".screen").appendChild(new2); // display is selected and new cell appended
      start++; // start incremented to allow number on grid increase as one descends down the grid
    }
    // gridSize++; //variable to allow user to change the grid size
  }
  //drawW();

  function fillScreen() {
    sizeOfGrid = gridSize
    dimension = 370.0 / gridSize;
    document.querySelector(".screen").innerHTML="";
    // function that draws the required number of rows
    for (let rows = 0; rows < sizeOfGrid; rows++) {
      drawW();
    }
    console.log("fillScreen gridSize",gridSize)
  }
  //fillScreen();

  function randomNumberMake() {
    //generates a whole number between 0 - 255
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    return number;
  }

  function createRgbColour() {
    //returns the RGB expression for the colours
    return `rgb( ${randomNumberMake()}, ${randomNumberMake()}, ${randomNumberMake()} )`;
  }

  function clearColours() {
    screen.innerHTML = "";
    //screen.style.backgroundColor = "#e1e4ea";
    gridSize = 0;
    miniDisplay.innerHTML = "000";
  }

  function gameBegin() {
    // game starts with 16 x 16 default grid size
    screen.innerHTML = ""; // clears the display
    if (!gridSize) {
      miniDisplay.innerHTML = 16;
      gridSize = 16;
      sizeOfGrid = gridSize;
    }

    fillScreen();
  }

  function courseSubtract() {
    // subtracts 10 from the grid size
    courseDecrement.onclick = () => {
      gridSize -= 10;
      miniDisplay.innerHTML = gridSize;
      console.log(miniDisplay.innerHTML);
      fillScreen();
    };
  }
  courseSubtract();

  function fineSubtract() {
    // subtracts 2 from the grid size
    fineDecrement.onclick = () => {
      console.log("gridSize", gridSize);
      gridSize -= 2;
      miniDisplay.innerHTML = "";
      miniDisplay.innerHTML = gridSize;
      console.log(miniDisplay.innerHTML);
      fillScreen();
    };
  }
  fineSubtract();

  function courseAdd() {
    // adds 10 to the grid size
    courseIncement.onclick = () => {
      gridSize += 10;
      miniDisplay.innerHTML = "";
      miniDisplay.innerHTML = gridSize;
      console.log(miniDisplay.innerHTML);
      fillScreen();
    };
  }
  courseAdd();

  function fineAdd() {
    // adds 2 to the grid size
    fineIncrement.onclick = () => {
      gridSize += 2;
      miniDisplay.innerHTML = "";
      miniDisplay.innerHTML = gridSize;
      console.log(miniDisplay.innerHTML);
      fillScreen();
    };
  }
  fineAdd();

  const pageLoad = document.createElement("img"); // creates new element for page load image
  pageLoad.src =
    "https://github.com/brian-w119/my-images/blob/main/SKETCH.gif?raw=true";

  function imageOnPageload() {
    // attaches image to screen
    //clearColours();
    screen.appendChild(pageLoad);
  }

  window.onload = () => {
    //cleas the screen and plays intro animation
    // clearColours();
    imageOnPageload();
    setTimeout(displayRules, 3000);
  };

  const instruction = [
    "Select a grid size between 16 and 64, then press ENTER. Press START to begin.",
  ];
  const speed = 60;
  let textPosition = 0;

  function displayRules() {
    //function for typewriter effect
    miniDisplay.innerHTML = "000";
    screen.innerHTML = instruction[0].substring(0, textPosition);
    if (textPosition++ != instruction[0].length) {
      setTimeout(displayRules, speed);
    }
  }
</script>
```

[image: []1]